# SQL Insert into duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, conditional-aggregation

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    lc.locationName,
    (SELECT SUM(c.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
     WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
       AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
       AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_ONE%' 
       AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_ONE_COUNT,
    (SELECT SUM(c.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
     WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
       AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
       AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_TWO%' 
       AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_TWO_COUNT,
    (SELECT SUM(c.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
     WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
       AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
       AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_THREE%' 
       AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_THREE_COUNT
FROM 
    Schedule AS sc WITH (NOLOCK) --/*This table has timeslotscount, serviceid*/
LEFT JOIN 
    ServiceList AS sv ON sv.ServiceId = sc.ServiceId --/*This table has locationid, serviceid(type1/type2/type3 depending on location[all locations has type1/2/3])*/
LEFT JOIN 
    Location AS lc ON sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId --/*This table has  locationid, locationname*/
```

I should explain the `SUM()`, there are differing dates on schedule such as

```
serviceId | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | count for this day
```

I want to get all the "count" of "serviceId" beyond today hence the 'date >= GETDATE()'

Basically I want the table to look like so:

```
LOCATION | TYPE_ONE_COUNT | TYPE_TWO_COUNT | TYPE_THREE_COUNT
```

I am able to get the values but I get them like so:

```
LocationOne | 12 |  0 |  0   
LocationOne | 0  | 12 |  0  
LocationOne | 0  |  0 | 34  
LocationTwo | 1  |  0 |  0  
LocationTwo | 0  | 42 |  0  
LocationTwo | 0  | 0  |  9
```

Whereas I want to display as

```
LocationOne | 12 | 12 | 34  
LocationTwo | 1  | 42 |  9
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Where I'm wrong, syntax/performance improvement, references, anything.

Comment: Stop splattering you code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). DISTINCT applies to the entire row - your attempt to condense to one row per location is incorrect. And notice the repeated logic in the subqueries which use the same table that your outer query is using. This is usually a logic flaw. Conditional aggregation is likely a better approach.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for pointing out the flaws in my query. I think I have read somewhere nolock helps improve run time so I just put them in. I did take it out now though. But thanks in any case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT lc.locationName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_ONE%' THEN sc.TimeSlotsCount ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE_ONE_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_TWO%' THEN sc.TimeSlotsCount ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE_TWO_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_THREE%' THEN sc.TimeSlotsCount ELSE 0 END) AS TYPE_THREE_COUNT 
FROM Location AS lc 
LEFT JOIN ServiceList AS sv ON sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId
LEFT JOIN Schedule AS sc ON sv.ServiceId = sc.ServiceId AND sc.Date >= GETDATE() 
GROUP BY lc.LocationId, lc.locationName;
```

Comment: Notes for OP. Notice the statement terminator. Use them - that's a best practice. Most likely the query should have an ORDER BY clause since order of rows almost always matters. Grouping tends to produce rows in a particular order but that is no guarantee. You might want to add a filter on the sv table join for those same three values used in the sum expressions. Lastly, schema qualify your object names.

Comment: And notice the join order. This makes more logical sense but only you can know what your goal is. I suspect the outer joins are not needed either.

Comment: Thank you both @SMor and @forpas! This does look a syntactically cleaner and logical than my original query. I would try to do the other suggestions made and see if it fits better to my current needs. Thank you so much for clearing up so many things for me.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways.  One is to simply perform one last operation:

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2332a4db686653b48c2caa09f80732cd)

Note also: I adjusted the original SQL, since `c.TimeSlotsCount` does not exist.  You have no `c` table/alias.  I added `TimeSlotsCount` to the `Schedule` table.  Adjust that as needed, based on the actual source of `TimeSlotsCount`.

```
WITH cte AS (
        Your above SQL from the question, without semicolon
     )
SELECT locationName
     , SUM(TYPE_ONE_COUNT)   AS TYPE_ONE_COUNT
     , SUM(TYPE_TWO_COUNT)   AS TYPE_TWO_COUNT
     , SUM(TYPE_THREE_COUNT) AS TYPE_THREE_COUNT
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY locationName
;
```

We could have also done a slightly different SUM in the original SQL, without the `DISTINCT` and with the `GROUP BY`, avoiding the extra CTE term.

But logically, these are the same.

Final SQL, using your SQL directly:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT
          lc.locationName,
          (SELECT SUM(s.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
           WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
             AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
             AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_ONE%' 
             AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_ONE_COUNT,
          (SELECT SUM(s.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
           WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
             AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
             AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_TWO%' 
             AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_TWO_COUNT,
          (SELECT SUM(s.TimeSlotsCount) FROM Schedule s 
           WHERE s.ServiceId = sv.ServiceId 
             AND sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId 
             AND sv.ServiceName LIKE '%TYPE_THREE%' 
             AND s.Date >= GETDATE()) AS TYPE_THREE_COUNT
      FROM 
          Schedule AS sc WITH (NOLOCK) --/*This table has timeslotscount, serviceid*/
      LEFT JOIN 
          ServiceList AS sv ON sv.ServiceId = sc.ServiceId --/*This table has locationid, serviceid(type1/type2/type3 depending on location[all locations has type1/2/3])*/
      LEFT JOIN 
          Location AS lc ON sv.LocationId = lc.LocationId --/*This table has  locationid, locationname*/
     )
SELECT locationName
     , SUM(TYPE_ONE_COUNT)   AS TYPE_ONE_COUNT
     , SUM(TYPE_TWO_COUNT)   AS TYPE_TWO_COUNT
     , SUM(TYPE_THREE_COUNT) AS TYPE_THREE_COUNT
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY locationName
;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking time to answer my query! I will definitely try this. I am not familiar with CTE although, will this have significant performance effects also? I'm a bit worried because looking at it, there are several tables and subqueries involved. Is there anyway I could shave off a few execution run time?

Comment: @JZnrgn Performance will likely match your original SQL.   1) Get it right.  2) Then make it fast.  There are a number of ways to structure this.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you also for introducing me to CTE! However for this thread I'm going to have to go to forpas and smor's advise as they have pointed out many wrongs in my original query. But in any case, thank you so much again!